# Transform on hovering is repeating

Tags: css, hover, transform

i have a code that uses **:hover** to make a button smaller.

```
.button:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(.2);
-ms-transform: scale(.2);
transform: scale(.2);
}
```

but when i tested it always renders the hover-effect again like an infinite loop.

Could somebody help me to make it work that it plays only one time on hovering?

https://jsfiddle.net/Robert_Wi/ropscbqw/2/

Tkank you.

Robert

Comment: it's because you make the element small so you loss the cursor on it. Better consider another container where you apply the hover effect

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that you are practically “removing” the element from under where the mouse cursor is hovering over, _because_ you are shrinking it to an incredible tiny size. Use an additional container element that stays the same size, apply :hover on that, and then shrink the button inside of it instead.

Comment: When the element scales down enough so that the mouse is no longer over it the hover state is removed as the mouse is not hovering the element anymore.

Comment: Change `scale value` from `0.2` to `0.8` and if you need quick hover then change the `linear` from 1 sec to lesser. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/15yjmfbk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

This is the solution:

Put it into a new container.

The code:
[demo][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Robert_Wi/ropscbqw/11/
```